# Trouble getting drop down's selected li to stay in a hover state

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulties with a drop down menu I created. If I go to any of the main list items and move my mouse away, the main list item goes back to its native state.

I created a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/7wmqdxv1/ to show what is going on.

The list items that are going back to black are:

```
<li><a href="myaccount.php">Manage</a>
<li><a href="">Reports</a>
```

etc.

I want the main list item to remain white when you move your mouse down the drop down list that displays. I have changed the list's hover color to white, everything, but I cannot get this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would have to move the hover statement from the `a` to the `li`

```
.signInBar li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.signInBar li:hover a{
    background-color: #282828;
    -o-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */

transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
```

}

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7wmqdxv1/1/)

Comment: Your answer works and is better than using javascript so I'll remove my own answer!

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you have the following rule:

```
.signInBar li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Change the selector to the following, and it will work. ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3ak6zuL5/))

```
.signInBar li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

The sub-menu items are children of the `li`, but not of the `a`, so when you hover on the sub-menu items, you are no longer hovering on the `a` item, but you are still hovering on the `li`. The direct descendent selector (`>`) is used here to make sure the rule is only applied to the same scope that it was applied to before, but could be removed if you want that rule to apply to all links that are children of the main navigation `li` entry.

Answer (score 1):

change following code into your css

```
.signInBar li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

instead of

```
.signInBar li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

> when you are hovering onto drop-down list your cursor comes out of
>   your `<a>` tag. that is the reason you need to put `:hover` state to
>   `<li>` tag